# Is there an `outer` or `exclusive or` operator equivalent to `inter` in KDB?

Tags: list, xor, kdb

Let's say I have the following two lists:

```
 x : `a`b`c`d;
 y : `a`b`e`f;
```

For the intersection, there is the `inter` operator:

```
q)x inter y
`a`b
```

Is there a similar operator to do the `EXCLUSIVE OR` such that I would get:

```
q)x outer y
`c`d`e`f
```

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the operation `except` will give you elements of one list that do not belong in another.

However in your case `x except y` would only give `` `c`d `` and `y except x` would only give `` `e`f ``.

Therefore you could use either;

```
q)(x except y),y except x
`c`d`e`f
```

or

```
q)(x union y) except (x inter y)
`c`d`e`f
```

or alternatively without using `except`

```
q)where(count each group (distinct x), distinct y)=1
`c`d`e`f
```

if you want to get a list of all exclusive elements.

Regards, Kevin

Comment: Nice. You could do away with the `union` and just make it `(x,y)except x inter y` - though it would leave duplicates as mentioned by Callum

Answer (score 5):

From Kevin's answers, the first will give duplicates if they are present in either, the last will give the distinct list. To use the function infix as you have requested, you need to define the function in the .q namespace

```
q).q.outer:{(x union y) except (x inter y)}
q)x outer y
`c`d`e`f
```